# HTML unable to open image despite correct location

Tags: html, asp.net, browser, href

I am having some trouble open a image (jpg) on the browser despite correct location. The rest of the image located in the folder are able to open.

I need some advise or diction how to approach this issue.

Link 1 --> Show my FTP
http://postimg.org/image/g3lofgv8r/

Link 2 --> Show the dictionray
http://postimg.org/image/7nw24mw81/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to url encode the value in the `src`-attribute of your image tag? (I find this link useful for a quick check: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

Like when your image filename is

`<img src="spaces and + sign in url.jpg" />`

you would encode it with

`<img src="spaces+and+%2B+sign+in+url.jpg" />`

Comment: I managed to solve this matter.
I am using IIS. Thus, iis server prevent the use of + and & symbol.

However to enable it, you need to change on your web config. However, it might exposed your security risk.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/URLs+that+containing+a+plus+symbol+can't+be+displayed
--------------------------------------------------------

Thank you user2056901 and sthzg. 
I am using urlencode now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue looks to me is the Space between name of image...either remove space or use underscore(_)...[image]